# C programming with functions

Tags: c, function, bubble-sort

I have got some more problems with the code. This program ask the user to specify the nr of throws then it throws 3 dices and add these 3 dices to sum.

Then another function sorts the sum form the smallest to the largest with a bubble sorting algorithm.

the first two functions seems to work but the program does not print out the result of the 3rd sorting function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 100

//This function ask the user for the amout of throws
int numberofthrows() {
    int throws
    printf("Type in the number of throws");
    scanf("%d", &throws);
    return throws;
}

//This function makes the random throws of 3 dices with regard to the number of throws    

int filler(int thrownr, int dice1[MAX], int dice2[MAX], int dice3[MAX], int    sum[MAX]) {
    int i, nr;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i <= thrownr; i++) {
        nr = rand()%6;
        dice1[i] = nr + 1;
        nr = rand()%6;
        dice2[i] = nr + 1;
        nr = rand()%6;
        dice3[i] = nr + 1;
        sum[i] = dice1[i] + dice2[i] + dice3[i];
    }

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j <= thrownr; j++) {
        printf("%d ", dice1[j]);
        printf("%d ", dice2[j]);
        printf("%d ", dice3[j]);
        printf("%d\n", sum[j]);
    }
}

//This function sorts the result in form the sum array

int sorter(int thrownr, int sum[MAX], int sortsum[MAX]) {
    int tmp, i, j, k, m;
    for(i = 0; i <= thrownr; i++) {
        sortsum[i] = sum[i];
    }
    for(m = 0; m <= 10; m++) {
        for(j = 0; j <= thrownr; i++) {
            if (sortsum[j] > sortsum[j+1]) {
                tmp = sortsum[j];
                sortsum[j] = sortsum[j+1];
                sortsum[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(k = 0; k <= thrownr; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", sortsum[k]);
        printf("%d\n", sum[k]);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dice1[MAX];
    int dice2[MAX];
    int dice3[MAX];
    int sum[MAX];
    int sortsum[MAX];
    int numberofthrows2;
    numberofthrows2 = numberofthrows();
    filler(numberofthrows2, dice1, dice2, dice3, sum);
    sorter(numberofthrows2, sum, sortsum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've edited out the excess vertical whitespace that made the code hard for reviewers to study because of all the scrolling it required in the small viewing window.  In the future please consider making it as easy as others for hard working reviewers to understand your code and the issue, and more of them may be inclined to help.  The edits have been submitted for peer review and may be approved that way, or you can click edit and you will see my proposed changes and can accept them yourself.

Comment: The question is not very focused.  I don't think you've isolated it down to a problem you couldn't resolve through some basic debugging techniques.  You may want to work on it a little more until you get it down to a real technical challenge and not just a basic bug in your code like we all have and have to fix regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for sorting is a bit wrong. Change

```
for(m = 0; m <= 10; m++)
```

To

```
for(m = 0; m <= thrownr-1; m++)
```

And

```
for(j = 0; j <= thrownr; i++)
```

To

```
for(j = 0; j < thrownr-m-1; i++)
```

To fix it. Also, call `srand` **once** at the start of `main`. Don't call it more than once in a program or you might get the same "random" numbers everytime you run your program.